# Windows API colored output to stdout in Powershell/cmd.exe

Tags: windows, colors, stdout, command-line-interface

Anyone know where to find a reference that describes how to output color on the Windows CLI interfaces using API and/or stdout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682010.aspx) has a function,  [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686047.aspx), that can be used to set the text foreground and background colours. Sample code is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686974.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

At least there is the color command:

```
color bg fg
```

where:

```
0: Black
1: Blue
2: Green
3: Cyan
4: Red
5: Purple
6: Yellow
7: Gray
8: Silver
9: Light blue
A: Lime
B: Light cyan
C: Light red
D: Light purple
E: Light yellow
F: White
```

Example:

```
color 80
```

Gives a silver background with black text.

Comment: The darwback of color is whenever you specify a color scheme, the whole screen all uses this scheme, including already-output colored text. In other word, you can see only one text color at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a reference but it should help you find what you're looking for on MSDN, check out:

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=457528.

You probably want to look up "WriteConsoleOutput".

Answer (score 0):

in powershell write-host takes -backgroundcolor and -foregroundcolor parameters

Comment: Even cooler, it accepts an array as a parameter! So this is valid and produces Pink: `write-host "I'm Pink" -ForegroundColor Red, Blue`

Comment: wow, that makes no sense at all to me. it uses the sum of the color values as the result?